# Missing Toolbar/Admin Bar on subdomain page using WordPress integration

Tags: admin-bar

My main WordPress installation is on www.example.com.

I have a sub-domain page which is like this: sub.example.com

In the `index.php` of the sub-domain I use:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( '../wp-blog-header.php' );
/** Loads the header for this page */
require('header.php');
```

In header I have:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

And in the footer:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

The problem I have is that the WordPress Toolbar is not loaded and even though I'm logged in on the main site, and on the sub-domain, this is not recognized.

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Generally speaking, wordpress will work on one domain only. A subdomain is a different domain, and auth cookies wont work there.

Comment: is_user_logged_in() function returns true though

Comment: There are many missing details here: why are you trying to get to a particular page through a subdomain? If I go to sub.domain.com and to www.domain.com; do I get the same content, generally speaking? On any case, I think that maybe this answer has some clues that would help you. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15335/how-to-transition-cookies-from-subdomain-domain-com-to-domain-com-with-minimal

Comment: I have define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.domain.com'); already so probably that's why the users are seen as logged in.

Comment: If you go to sub.domain/wp-admin/ are you able to log in? Again, WP doesn't like very much (and with a good enough reason) you accessing the same content on different domains, so I think that generally speaking, you are setting yourself to disappointment here.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work.