# Serving Cookies From A Different Domain or Sub-Domain

Tags: cookies

The [WordPress Codex clearly states](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Set_Cookie_Domain) that if your website is served from `example.com`, for the sake of performance, you can have the cookies served from `www.example.com` by adding this to your wp-config.php:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'www.example.com');
```

**Problem:**

- The cookies are still being served from `example.com` and not `www.example.com`. What's wrong? or does this no longer work?

***PS:** Edited to be precise.*

Comment: So well that I've searched, I could find no "exact duplicate" to this. [Here's something very related and helpful](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7061/10691) (for my own reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I mis-interpreted what's said in the codex. So, here's the thing...

This is what WordPress does by default: `define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.example.com');` — which means, cookies are sent with all the sub-domains, including `example.com` itself, even if your WordPress website itself is hosted on `www.example.com`.

Basically the point is, when your WordPress site is served from `www.example.com`, you can also have the cookies sent only with `www.example.com` and not other sub-domains, by adding this in your wp-config.php:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'www.example.com');
```

So, at most, what the aforementioned code does is restrict the cookies to the sub-domain that serves your WP site.

**NOTE:** And just in case it's not clear -- it's pointless to use `define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'www.example.com');` when your site itself is served from `example.com` or some other sub-domain, and not 'www.example.com'.