# Where is the wordpress session stored?

Tags: session

I need to be able to validate the session integrity from an external app. I can't find where is the session stored in wordpress?

I built a restful app that will receive the session token as a header and I would like to be able to load the user associdated to that session. Is that possible? I'm sure it is, I just can't find anywhere. I tried to lookup the code but I get lost quickly.. Anyone can at least point me in which table I should check?

Answer (score 2):

How WordPress stores cookies (client-side, as @birgire stated):
https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies

I doubt this will ever work from a separate subdomain as the cookie domain is usually fully-qualified to the WordPress `siteurl` (someone feel free to correct me.)

If you were doing it with another app on the *same* domain, you'd need to make use of the `wp_validate_auth_cookie()` function (in `wp-includes/pluggable.php`) - that looks at `$_COOKIES`, generates a hash from the user's database record and checks if it matches the cookie. If it does, you get their user ID back.

Comment: Maybe the [COOKIE_DOMAIN](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7061/26350) constant is useful here?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress sessions are stored according to your PHP settings, by default in your file system. Check out your **PHP.ini** file for the **session.save_path** setting. You should note that WordPress doesn't create a session unless the user logs in.

Assuming your "external" app is on the same server and running as PHP, you could simply open the same session using:

```
session_id($session_token);
session_start();
```

Comment: WordPress is not storing server-side sessions for logged in users, but uses client-side cookies instead, to my knowledge. Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's on the same server, different subdomain. How would that allow me to load the session? thanks for you reply

Comment: @birgire I also learned that. But after Oliver's answer, I's in doubt actually. +1 for your comment.